# Defining a function of a function with arbitrary variable name

Tags: function-construction

Is there a way to pass a function into a function you write such that the function can be of an arbitrary variable?

What I want to do is something like...

```
func[f_[x]] := (f[x])^2
g[y_] := y^2
func[g[y]]
```

```
Out[]= y^4
```

So far I know how to square an expression, but not a function unless it explicitly uses the same var `x` in both `func` and `g`.

(Also as a side note, why does...

```
func[f_[x]] := (f[x])^2
g[y_] := Sin[y]
func[g[x]]
```

work, but not for non-trig functions like `Exp`?

*Might be because of other things in my notebook, hopefully not*)

Comment: func[f_[x]] := (f[x])^2;
g[y_] := Power[y, 2];
func[g[x]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the problem is that  `g[x]` evaluates before `func` is evaluated. Thus the function `g` disappears, and the definition of `func` does not apply, unless by accident, the value of `g[x]` has the form `f[x]`.  To prevent this, evaluation of the argument of `func` must be held.

```
ClearAll[func];
SetAttributes[func, HoldAll];
func[f_[x_]] := (f[x])^2;

g[y_] := Power[y, 2];
func[g[x]]
```

> ```
> (*  x^4  *)
> ```

Trace shows what happens when the argument is not held.  The first thing is that `g[x]` is evaluated.  When `g[x]` yield `x^2`, it has the internal form `Power[x, 2]`, which has two arguments; however the pattern for `func[f_[x_]]` is only for when it has one argument.  In the second case, `Sin[x]` has the form `f[x]`, which matches the definition of `func`.

```
g[y_] := y^2;
func[g[x]] // Trace
```

> ```
> (*  {{g[x], Power[x, 2]}, func[Power[x, 2]]}  *)
> ```

```
g[y_] := Sin[y];
func[g[x]] // Trace
```

> ```
> (*  {{g[x], Sin[x]}, func[Sin[x]], Sin[x]^2}  *)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A replacement rule of this form seems to work. I hope it helps.

```
func[arg_] := arg /. f_[x___] :> (f[x])^2
g[y_] := y^2
func[g[y]]
```